# Posting Array using JSON & JQuery to a C# Web Api back end

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api

I have the following JQuery:

```
var dataToSend = {
    list: [{ Code: 'ABC', BusinessDate: '31-Jan-2012' }, { Code: 'DEF', BusinessDate: '31-Jan-2012' }]    
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    url: '/api/dashboard/post/',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify( dataToSend), 
    success: function (result) {
        alert('done');
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

and the following method at on the server:

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public void Post(List<MyObject> list)
        {

        }
```

MyObjects definition:

```
public class MyObject
{

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string Code { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string BusinessDate { get; set; }

}
```

The method gets hit, but shows no results in the collection. If I change the parameter to be:

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public void Post(MyObject list)
        {
           // return new JsonResult();
        }
```

and only pass through the first item in the collection, I receive the object with the data in the web api method without issue, it's only when trying to pass arrays that I seem to have a problem.

Fidler shows this as the JSON:

> {"list":[{"Code":"ABC","BusinessDate":"31-Jan-2012"},{"Code":"DEF","BusinessDate":"31-Jan-2012"}]}

Could someone please explain what I am doing incorrectly which so I can not receive arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add  in your headers. `content-type :application/json`

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

What your JSON is sending is essentially this: an object with a property called list that then has a list of objects in it. You have one unnecessary redirection. Try to remove the `list:` from the data you are sending and directly send the list as your parameter.